# What does the fancy R symbol mean as written here?

Tags: math, computation-theory, turing-machines

This is an assigned question I have, and I'm not sure how to interpret the R-like symbol in the exponent position. Does it mean the Turing machine should accept variable numbers of repetitions of *w*?

[image: Fancy R]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it either belongs on math.stackexchange or cstheory.stackexchange - you're much more likely to get specialist help from those communities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation *w*<sup>R</sup> probably means “*w* reversed.” The problem most likely asks that the Turing machine shall, if it starts with a word *w* on its tape, append a `#` and then *w* reversed. Afterwards, it shall accept (i.e. terminate). For instance, if the tape contains `example` in the beginning, it should contain `example#elpmaxe` after the Turing machine ran.

Answer (score 1):

In this case it may mean reversal, which is what I was able to find at the link for this [300 level CS course](http://faculty.simpson.edu/lydia.sinapova/www/cmsc365/LN365_Lewis/L05-Languages.htm).  Hopefully that helps.